# Adjust Unity Dependency injection to use Lazy<T> / Func<T>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm working on a project that uses Unity Dependancy injection but the load performance is slowly getting worse.  I am trying to adjust the code to utilise `Lazy<T>` (or `Func<T>`) so i'm trying to find a way to either register the classes with the container using `Lazy<T>` (or `Func<T>`) or have some sort of factory that could either adjust the registered types or the constructor but i am not able to seem to find a possible way to do this

At present i have numerous service classes like

```
public Service1(IClassLogic<GetReq, GetRes> getClass, IClassLogic<AddReq, AddRes> addClass, IClassLogic<UpdateReq, UpdateRes> updateClass, IClassLogic<DeleteReq, DeleteRes> deleteClass....){...}
```

then i have registrations similar to

```
container.RegisterType<IClassLogic<GetReq, GetRes>, GetClass>();
container.RegisterType<IClassLogic<AddReq, AddRes>, AddClass>();
container.RegisterType<IClassLogic<UpdateReq, UpdateRes>, UpdateClass>();
container.RegisterType<IClassLogic<DeleteReq, DeleteRes>, DeleteClass>();
...
```

Ideally i would like not to have to go an change all the signatures to

```
public Service1(Lazy<IClassLogic<GetReq, GetRes>> getClass, Lazy<IClassLogic<AddReq, AddRes>> addClass...
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you know the performance problems stem from Unity?

Comment: Some of the classes that i'd be instantiating are fairly large and may instantiate numerous interfaces themselves so i'm looking at how i can streamline that load time Lazy<T> seems the best way - there is other aspects of the code that is being reviewed for performance/bottlenecks this is just one section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off some tips concerning DI in general:

- You're right, you do not want to change the signature of the constructor. You're IoC container (Unity in your case) should enable you to design the interfaces and consumers as you like. Otherwise it isn't a good container.
- When struggling starting with DI (and containers) I would advise wiring it up yourself. This gives you great insight in how it works and provides flexibility. Mark Seemann has written a lot about this stuff.
- Your service's dependencies seem awfully crowded. Can't you refactor to less dependencies by combining some (maybe by a [Facade](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern))?
- Making interfaces specific (not generic) makes things a lot simpler. Generics sometimes cause more harm than good.

I've coded up a quick example which compiles (I haven't tested it). I've used a generic interface in line with your example but used some fake implementation and string types as generic params (which aren't used):

If this is an implementation of an interface:

```
public class ClassLogic : IClassLogic<string, string>
{
    public void Do()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then you could implement a provider which only creates the implementation when needed (via a given Func) like this:

```
public class ClassLogicProvider : IClassLogic<string, string>
{
private readonly Func<IClassLogic<string, string>> innerLogicFactory;

    public ClassLogicProvider(Func<IClassLogic<string, string>> innerLogicFactory)
    {
        this.innerLogicFactory = innerLogicFactory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var classLogic = this.innerLogicFactory();
        classLogic.Do();
    }
}
```

And wire it up like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
Func<IClassLogic<string, string>> classLogicFunc = () =>
        {
            // Create implementation on demand
            return new ClassLogic();
        };
container.RegisterType<IClassLogic<string, string>>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => {
                return new ClassLogicProvider(classLogicFunc);
            })
        );
```

This should give you the desired Lazy creation when to implementation is needed.

Comment: I've read a few posts by Mark Seemann while trying to get my head around the whole area of DI.  On the service's dependencies, they are quite crowded and its possible this is one of the things i'm going to have to tackle to clean this whole section up.  This is all built on a design that was out of my hands at the time.

Comment: Concerning your first bullet point: If he needs to change his objects and designs to start using deferred object instanciation, it has nothing to do with the dependency injection.

Comment: @Tipx The point that I was trying to make was that Lazy instantiation is independent from constructor design concerning dependencies (or can be). I didn't mean he/she should change the design. So, you're right, you shouldn't have to redesign an object when you want to use DI.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent using `Func<T>` and `Lazy<T>` as dependencies to prevent slow object graph initialization. These are leaky abstractions, because they leak implementation details into the consumer. The implementation detail here is that such service is costly to create.

The fact that it takes too much time to create a dependency is an indication that your injection constructors do too much, while they should be [simple, fast and reliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Another obvious problem is the Single Responsibility Principle violation in your components. Having more than 5 dependencies in a constructor is a code smell and an indication of a Single Responsibility Principle violation. Some containers get slower when you need to resolve really big object graphs, but when you make your components small and focussed, this problem will quite likely go away, since the object graph to construct will be much smaller.

Comment: I do agree that the constructor is too big and the simple fast reliable focus is right but this is inherited code and each service has to service x number of methods relating to them, each of these were broken into separate classes implementing a common interface and applied to the constructor, so now i'm attempting to work around it with out causing a massive code rewrite.

Comment: @Steven: Using a `Func<T>` isn't necessarily a sign that something is costly to create, right? You might want to avoid having single method interfaces, for instance. Or you could have some things that are tied to the `HttpRequest` and aren't alive on Controller creation.

Comment: @bump: `Func<T>` isn't necessarily a sign that something is costly to create, there are other reasons you wish to inject `Func<T>` into your applicaiton components, but most of these imply that the abstraction is leaking. About single method interfaces, you should certainly not avoid them, since methods with more than one interface are in most cases an [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) violation.